# Sending GET or POST request with Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use `HttpURLConnection` class in Groovy to send GET and POST (with Jsonbody) request to an api. But what can I tell you. With `HttpURLConnection` it is soo difficult. I do not know how to use it. There is not even a send method. It looks like when you call `getResponseCode()` this method sends a request. Then you have to use `InputStream` and for POST you even have to use `OutputStream`. Oh my god. For what ?? I am used to handy libraries like Jersey Client. But this `HttpURLConnection`  is just a nightmare. I have to use it because I have jenkinsfile and in my pipeline I need to upload something. And that is possible with calling an REST Api. What do you think about `HttpURLConnection`  ? Does someone know a good website with a GET Request and a POST Request with a body.

Comment: Googling ‘httpurlconnection post’ gave the following: https://www.baeldung.com/httpurlconnection-post. Was there something not covered there?

Comment: Here is example for GET request  https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request

Comment: You should read this. He also complains about this not very usable HttpUrlConnection class. https://techtavern.wordpress.com/2015/11/30/httpurlconnection-and-get-query-parameters/

Comment: You said you had to use it. If I had other options I would probably use `RestTemplate` from spring to make a http request. But if that’s what you’re stuck with, that’s how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do https://www.baeldung.com/httpurlconnection-post

Making it Groovy should be pretty trivial.

If you are doing an HTTP request and you want to use vanilla Java or Groovy, then I would recommend using `HttpClient` and `HttpRequest.Builder`; it's somewhat fluid. And you supply a `BodyHandler` object, which can be used to get the content however you like it (String, JSON Object, whatever).